# Check for double integers in group

Tags: vb.net, integer

I have 64 integers in a magic square ranging from Label1 to Label64.

How can I easily check if any two(or more) of these integers are equal to each other, since double numbers are not allowed in a magic square?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Language: Visual Basic .NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will just assume that all labels have one parent control.

Then you can just use a simple loop like this:

```
Dim container As Panel ' The container
For i As Integer = 1 to 64
Dim li As Label = CType(container.Controls("Label" & i), Label)
For j As Integer = 1 to 64
    Dim lj As Label = CType(container.Controls("Label" & j), Label)
        If li.text = lj.text Then
            ' Duplicate found
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: That doesn't work, mate. I always recieve a positive result since it compares a label with itself too.

EDIT: I fixed the problem. Add "And li.Name <> lj.Name" to line 6 and it works. Thanks for the help though, wouldn't have been able to do it without your approach.